# Why Git fail to connect to local repository with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins-plugins

Getting the following error in the Source Code Management section of the Configure link in Jenkins:

Failed to connect to repository : Command "'git.cmd ls-remote -h 'http://machine1.abc/Repository1.git HEAD'" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed

Comment: At the risk of sounding obvious, it looks like you need to supply credentials, i.e. a username and password...

Comment: where is that set in Jenkins?

Comment: Apparently inside a [netrc file](http://dustint.com/post/299/hudson-jenkins-and-git-http-authentication). I can't vouch for this solution, however.

Comment: thanks.  Not working, but it seems like it should.  the recommended _netrc test via curl doesn't seem to detect the host in the _netrc file.